# How to find the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ so that the equation has four distinct integral solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ so that the equation
$$x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d=0,$$
where $d = \dfrac{c^2}{a^2}$
has four distinct integral solutions.

With *Maple*, I found some equations like this picture. I don't know how to start with *Mathematica*.
[image]

Comment: Look up the `FindInstance` function.

Comment: My idea was `FindInstance` as well which works for easier problems: `eq = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x; stance[Equal @@@ Flatten@Solve[eq == 0, x], {x, a, b, c}, Integers, 3]`. However, for the example of the OP that doesn't work since the general solution contains complex terms. Does anyone know a *general answer* to such problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `p`, `q`, `r` and `s`  be the roots, so that the polynomial can be factored as:

```
poly = (x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s);
```

One requirement is that $d=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$, which means:

```
eqn = Coefficient[poly, x, 1]^2 == Coefficient[poly, x, 0] Coefficient[poly, x, 3]^2
cond = Coefficient[poly, x, 3] != 0
```

> (-p q r - p q s - p r s - q r s)^2 == p q r (-p - q - r - s)^2 s
>
> -p - q - r - s != 0

The other requirement is that each root is distinct. Putting these together, we can use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance):

```
sol = FindInstance[
    eqn && -10 < p < q < r < s < 10 && p + q + r + s != 0,
    {p, q, r, s},
    Integers,
    10
]
```

> {{p -> -8, q -> -6, r -> -4, s -> -3}, {p -> -3, q -> -2, r -> 6, 
>     s -> 9}, {p -> -2, q -> -1, r -> 4, s -> 8}, {p -> -9, q -> -6, r -> 2, 
>     s -> 3}, {p -> -9, q -> -6, r -> 4, s -> 6}, {p -> -9, q -> -3, r -> 2, 
>     s -> 6}, {p -> -6, q -> -4, r -> 6, s -> 9}, {p -> -9, q -> -2, r -> 3, 
>     s -> 6}, {p -> -3, q -> -1, r -> 3, s -> 9}, {p -> -8, q -> -4, r -> 3, 
>     s -> 6}}

The corresponding polynomials are then:

```
Expand[poly /. sol] //Column //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  x^4+21 x^3+158 x^2+504 x+576 \\
>  x^4-10 x^3-15 x^2+180 x+324 \\
>  x^4-9 x^3-2 x^2+72 x+64 \\
>  x^4+10 x^3-15 x^2-180 x+324 \\
>  x^4+5 x^3-72 x^2-180 x+1296 \\
>  x^4+4 x^3-57 x^2-72 x+324 \\
>  x^4-5 x^3-72 x^2+180 x+1296 \\
>  x^4+2 x^3-63 x^2+36 x+324 \\
>  x^4-8 x^3-18 x^2+72 x+81 \\
>  x^4+3 x^3-58 x^2-72 x+576 \\
> \end{array}$

**Addendum**

The OP requested all solutions with conditions given on the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

To answer the new question, let's first simplify `eqn` as in @JM's answer:

```
eqn2 = FullSimplify[eqn]
```

> (q r - p s) (-p r + q s) (p q - r s) == 0

Now, suppose one of the roots is zero. Without loss of generality, take $p=0$:

```
eqn2 /. p -> 0
```

> -q^2 r^2 s^2 == 0

The only way the above equation can be satisfied is if one of $q$, $r$ or $s$ is also zero. But then, the roots would not be distinct. So, the combination:

```
(q r-p s) (-p r+q s) (p q-r s)==0 && p < q < r < s
```

implies that none of the variables are 0. Another way of seeing this is with:

```
Reduce[eqn2 && p < q < r < s && p q r s == 0, Integers]
```

> False

Now, let's examine the conditions in your comment for `a` and `d`:

```
-20 <= a <= 50
-20 <= b <= 50
-20 <= c <= 150
-20 <= d <= 150
```

or:

```
condA = -50 <= SymmetricPolynomial[1, {p, q, r, s}] <= 20
condB = -20 <= SymmetricPolynomial[2, {p, q, r, s}] <= 50
condC = -150 <= SymmetricPolynomial[3, {p, q, r, s}] <= 20
condD = -20 <= SymmetricPolynomial[4, {p, q, r, s}] <= 150
```

> -50 <= p + q + r + s <= 20
>
> -20 <= p q + p r + q r + p s + q s + r s <= 50
>
> -150 <= p q r + p q s + p r s + q r s <= 20
>
> -20 <= p q r s <= 150

The natural attempt would be to use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) with the above conditions. However, [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) is unable to make progress within a reasonable amount of time:

```
TimeConstrained[
    Solve[
        eqn2 && condA && condB && condC && condD && p < q < r < s,
        {p, q, r, s},
        Integers
    ],
    250
]
```

> $Aborted

Restricting the range over which $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ can vary, and reducing the number of conditions that must be satisfied helps. For instance:

```
Solve[
    eqn2 && condA && condD && -3 < p < q < r < s < 3,
    {p, q, r, s},
    Integers
]
```

> {{p -> -2, q -> -1, r -> 1, s -> 2}}

The conditions `condB` and `condC` can be imposed afterwards, but the range must be large enough to encompass all possible solutions. Examining `condA` and `condD` (and realizing that none of the roots are 0) suggests that the smallest possible value for `p` is -52, and the largest possible value for `s` is 25. Let's verify:

```
Reduce[p < -52 && q < r < s && condA && condD && q r s != 0, {p, q, r, s}, Integers]
Reduce[s > 25 && p < q < r && condA && condD && p q r != 0, {p, q, r, s}, Integers]
```

> False
>
> False

Hence, we can perform the following [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
sol = Solve[
    eqn2 && condA && condD && -53 < p < q < r < s < 26,
    {p, q, r, s},
    Integers
];
Length[sol]
```

> 67

Imposing `condB` and `condC` (and $a \neq 0$):

```
final = Cases[sol, v_ /; (condB && condC && p+q+r+s != 0 /. v)];
```

yields the following polynomials:

```
Expand[(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s) /. final] //Column //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  x^4+12 x^3+47 x^2+72 x+36 \\
>  x^4+3 x^3-8 x^2-12 x+16 \\
>  x^4-5 x^3-20 x^2+60 x+144 \\
>  x^4-4 x^3-17 x^2+24 x+36 \\
>  x^4-8 x^3-18 x^2+72 x+81 \\
>  x^4-12 x^3-13 x^2+144 x+144 \\
>  x^4-3 x^3-8 x^2+12 x+16 \\
>  x^4-6 x^3-7 x^2+36 x+36 \\
>  x^4-9 x^3-2 x^2+72 x+64 \\
>  x^4-12 x^3+7 x^2+120 x+100 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: How can I find all equations, for example, `-20 <=a<=50, -20 <=b<=50, -20 <=c<=150, -20 <=d<=150`?

Comment: Yes, the symmetric polynomials (i.e. Vieta) were how I arrived at the main equation in my solution (via pen and paper). Nice to see the expansion of the idea!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Call the distinct integers $p,q,r,s$.  Then find an instance in which
$$x^4+a x^3 +bx^2 +cx+d = (x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s) .$$

```
f = (x - p) (x - q) (x - r) (x - s);
Collect[f, x]
d = Coefficient[f, x, 0];
c = Coefficient[f, x, 1];
a = Coefficient[f, x, 3];
soln = First@FindInstance[
   {d == c^2/a^2, p != q != r != s},
   {p, q, r, s}]
f /. soln // Expand

(*
{p -> 8, q -> -6, r -> -12, s -> 9}
5184 + 72 x - 162 x^2 + x^3 + x^4
*)
```

Another solution can be found:

```
skip = {p, q, r, s} /. soln
sol2 = First@FindInstance[
   {d == c^2/a^2, p != q != r != s, Not[MemberQ[skip, p]]},
   {p, q, r, s}, Integers]
f/.sol2//Expand

(*
{p -> -1, q -> -2, r -> -4, s -> -8}
64 + 120 x + 70 x^2 + 15 x^3 + x^4
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

(I am not at a computer with *Mathematica*, so I will have to defer explanation for another time.)

```
With[{n = 20, (* number of instances *), bound = 10,
           seed = 10 (* seed the PRNG *)},
          (x - p) (x - q) (x - r) (x - s) /.
          FindInstance[(p q - r s) (q s - p r) (q r - p s) == 0 &&
                                   -bound < p < q < r < s < bound, {p, q, r, s},
                                    Integers, n, RandomSeeding -> seed]]
```

should return `n` solutions; change `seed` to see other solutions, or increase `n` for more solutions.

Comment: How can I find all equations, for example, `-20 <=a<=50, -20 <=b<=50, -20 <=c<=150, -20 <=d<=150`?

Comment: Why did you not put that restriction in your question?

Comment: I am sory about this. Can I edit my question?

Answer (score 3):

`FindInstance` can be slow, and it is not known *a priori* how many solutions are possible. I tried a different approach. It is fast compared to `FindInstance` and `Solve`. I think it gives all the solutions, but is inelegant because of all the duplicates to delete.

Roots $\{p,q,r,s\}$ of a quartic multiply together to give the integer polynomial coefficient $d$, which is required to equal $c^2/a^2>0$. Given square $d$, find factorisations into 4 factors with MultiplicativePartitionsMrW from @Mr.Wizard, then test for $c^2/a^2=d$.

```
MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[n_, 1, ___] := {{n}}

MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[n_, k_, x_: 2] := 
   Join @@ Table[
      If[q < x, {}, 
         Apply[{q, ##} &, 
            MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[n/q, k - 1, q], {1}]],
       {q, Take[#, Ceiling[Length[#]/k]] &[Divisors[n]]}]
```

We want all factorisations having 4 parts, found with 4 factors $\ge 2$, or by prepending $\{1\}$ to the solution with 3 factors $\ge 2$, or prepending $\{1,1\}$ to solutions with 2 factors $\ge 2$.

```
pqrs[d_] := 
   Join[
      MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[d, 4], 
      Map[Join[{1}, #] &, MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[d, 3]],
      Map[Join[{1, 1}, #] &, MultiplicativePartitionsMrW[d, 2]]
   ]
```

There are 8 combinations of signs of $\{p,q,r,s\}$ giving positive $d$.

```
signs[{p_, q_, r_, s_}] :=
   {{p, q, r, s}, {-p, -q, r, s}, {-p, q, -r, s}, {-p, q, r, -s},
    {p, -q, -r, s}, {p, -q, r, -s}, {p, q, -r, -s}, {-p, -q, -r, -s}}
```

Given roots $\{p,q,r,s\}$ corresponding to $d=p*q*r*s$, return coefficients $\{1,a,b,c,d\}$ if $a\ne 0$ and $d=c^2/a^2$.

```
abcd[{p_, q_, r_, s_}] :=
   With[{a = -p - q - r - s, c = -q r (p + s) - p s (q + r)},
      If[a != 0 && a^2 p q r s == c^2,
        {1, a, q (p + r + s) + p (r + s) + r s, c, p q r s}, {}]
   ]
```

Given square $d$, find solutions, if any, for coefficients $\{1,a,b,c,d\}$ with `QuarticSolution[d]`.

```
QuarticSolution[d_] :=
   DeleteCases[
      DeleteDuplicates[Map[abcd,
         Select[
            Flatten[Map[signs, pqrs[d]], 1],
            Length[#] === Length[DeleteDuplicates[#]] &]
      ]],
   {}]
```

For example,

`QuarticSolution[16]`

> {{1, -3, -8, 12, 16}, {1, 3, -8, -12, 16}}

These are the 10 solutions with the additional constraints on the coefficients. Timing is 8ms.

```
With[{maxd = 150},
   Flatten[Table[
      Select[
         QuarticSolution[d],
         -20 <= #[[2]] <= 50 && -20 <= #[[3]] <= 50 &&
         -20 <= #[[4]] <= 150 && -20 <= #[[5]] <= maxd &],
      {d, Range[Sqrt[maxd]]^2}], 1]
]
```

> {{1, -3, -8, 12, 16},{1, 3, -8, -12, 16}, {1, -6, -7, 36, 
>     36}, {1, -4, -17, 24, 36}, {1, 12, 47, 72, 36}, {1, -9, -2, 72, 
>     64}, {1, -8, -18, 72, 81}, {1, -12, 7, 120, 100}, {1, -5, -20, 60, 
>     144}, {1, -12, -13, 144, 144}}

Comment: I can not get the results.

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing comma in the definition for `pqrs`, now fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the results.

Comment: I got 99 equations about 8 seconds.